# Twitter-text count for iOS is not working properly

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, special-characters, charactercount

I have already referred this link https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text/tree/master/objc but I think this is not updated. It still shows twitter-text with 140 characters and also it is in objective-c. It do not provide proper count of some special characters same as in twitter official. It would be of great help if someone can please help with the latest 280-character twitter count API for iOS in swift. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you are saying correct : https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text/search?q=140&unscoped_q=140 140 is everywhere.

Comment: Are you using the v2 version of the parsing configuration file? That one has the updates for 280. We don't provide an official Swift implementation, but there's an unofficial one here https://gist.github.com/hebertialmeida/d868bd58efe8b5240e4ef8b542107099

Comment: @AndyPiper Thank you Andy. The above link was a great help.:) If you want you can post your above comment in answer and I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the v2 version of the parsing configuration file? That one has the updates for 280. We don't provide an official Swift implementation, but there's an unofficial one here https://gist.github.com/hebertialmeida/d868bd58efe8b5240e4ef8b542107099